# Control images based on previously visited page history

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

I am implementing Google's map and markers in my site.  Each marker references a page that the user can view.  Is it possible to use the visited pages info of the page in JS/jQuery?

The data I get for the markers comes from ajax postbacks.  When the data comes back, I plot the markers.

I would like to use a marker of a different color if the underlying page has been visited.

Any suggestions?

If it matters, it is an aspx page.

Answer (score 2):

You need to save the url of the visited pages in cookie or local storage or database then when making your ajax request assign a different marker image to ones that link to those urls